# Mac Terminal - Running Two commands at the same time

Tags: macos, terminal

UPDATE: How could I run:

```
osascript -e 'set desktopImage to POSIX file "~/image.jpg"
tell application "Finder"
set desktop picture to desktopImage
end tell'
```

through a .command file?

I'm trying to make a song play via terminal, then at a certain time in the song, echo something in terminal.

At first I tried:

```
afplay song.mp3; sleep 30; echo Foo
```

But sleep 30 and echo Foo weren't being run until the afplay task had been completed, which was after the song had finished playing.

I also tried creating two other .command files, then getting them to be both ran:

```
batch song.command; batch echo.command
```

song.command being:

```
afplay song.mp3
```

And echo.command being:

```
sleep 30; echo Foo
```

But the echo.command wouldn't execute until the everything in song.command had been done.

I need to somehow echo something about 30 seconds through the song.

Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following script should work:

```
#!/bin/sh

play() {
    afplay song.mp3
}

doecho() {
    sleep 30
    echo Foo
}

play &
doecho &
```

Comment: You don't need subshells here: `afplay song.mp3 & { sleep 30; echo Foo; }` should work well.

Comment: I'm surprised!  You might want to refer to [Grouping Commands](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Grouping) in the manual.

Comment: @devnull That works, but the console is blighted with `[1]+  Done ...` which doesn't happen with the subshells, so you'd need `>/dev/null`... so subshells will do.

Comment: Needless to say that.  If not within a subshell, you'd get notifications for background commands..

Comment: I'm not *sure* about that!

Comment: It doesn't run the echo Foo command or sleep 30 until afplay has finished running.

Comment: @HudsonSerge That's unusual; I wasn't able to test it with `afplay` but I did test it with `echo`, which appeared to work fine.  Are you sure you got the exact syntax correct?

Comment: I tried running both 
`afplay cyrus.mp3 & { sleep 42; bash wallpaper.command; }` 
and 
`(afplay song.mp3 &); (sleep 30; echo Foo)`
But the echo didn't seem to execute until afplay had finished running.

Comment: @HudsonSerge And how long does `song.mp3` play for?

Comment: 1 minute and 13 seconds, but at 30 seconds into the song, I want to echo Foo.

Comment: @HudsonSerge You are right; my test wasn't extensive enough.  I have updated my answer.